# Is there a way to see the source of a pcode file (.p) in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to open a pcode file (.p) in MATLAB?

Comment: Related. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013177/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If by 'open' you mean *edit* - then certainly not. 'p' in pcode is for 'protected' - its main design goal is deploying a functional component while protecting its source.

If by 'open' you mean *run* - then certainly yes. [Quoting the manual:](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f7-38053.html#bsc58yj-1)

> You invoke the resulting P-code file in the same way you invoke the MATLAB .m source file from which it was derived. For example, to invoke file myfun.p, type
>
> [out, out2, ...] = myfun(in1, in2, ...);

Comment: I know some ways for running it. but i don't know any way for editting it.
However,thanks for the answer.

Comment: That's what my answer says: there is *no* way of editing it. There will never be. The role of p-code is to be able to send components without revealing your source code.

Comment: Perhaps with IDA pro and tons of patience you can get access to certain fragments. It's not worth the effort, though, and probably violates the license agreement.