# how to open a matlab p-code file

Tags: file, matlab

Does anybody know how I can see the code of a matlab p-code file?

Comment: Related. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080311/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

p-code files exist specifically so that you can share code so that others can't look at it. In other words: You cannot see the code of a Matlab p-code file.