# How to see .p files' required input?

Tags: matlab, file-type

I have an .p file, this has to take some inputs and give me results, but I don't know which inputs I have to give to it. Does anyone know how can I learn it? after writing its name opening parenthesis is not working.

Comment: A related, but not duplicate, question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080311/is-there-a-way-to-see-the-source-of-a-pcode-file-p-in-matlab

Answer (score 3):

You cannot see the code of a Matlab p-code file.

p-code files exists so that one can share code in order that others can't look at it.

type on matlab command window;

```
help <p-code file name>
```

(if the corresponding .m has comments sections for its inputs and return values, or other documentations, you can probably see them)

You could probably get some idea for its inputs, from the error thrown just by typing the p-code file name.