# Barrier Function in Matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, barrier

Where can I find the implementation of barrier function in Matlab?
I am trying to see how the algorithm `interior-point` is implemented, and this is what I found in the end of `fmincon.m`

```
elseif strcmpi(OUTPUT.algorithm,interiorPoint)
    defaultopt.MaxIter = 1000; defaultopt.MaxFunEvals = 3000; defaultopt.TolX = 1e-10;
    defaultopt.Hessian = 'bfgs';
    mEq = lin_eq + sizes.mNonlinEq + nnz(xIndices.fixed); % number of equalities
    % Interior-point-specific options. Default values for lbfgs memory is 10, and 
    % ldl pivot threshold is 0.01
    options = getIpOptions(options,sizes.nVar,mEq,flags.constr,defaultopt,10,0.01); 

    [X,FVAL,EXITFLAG,OUTPUT,LAMBDA,GRAD,HESSIAN] = barrier(funfcn,X,A,B,Aeq,Beq,l,u,confcn,options.HessFcn, ...
        initVals.f,initVals.g,initVals.ncineq,initVals.nceq,initVals.gnc,initVals.gnceq,HESSIAN, ...
        xIndices,options,optionFeedback,finDiffFlags,varargin{:});
```

So I want to see what's in barrier but failed.

```
edit barrier.m
```

I got:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The barrier function is defined in a [p-file](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/protect-your-source-code.html) (precisely located in `MATLABROOT/toolbox/optim/optim/barrier.p`).

Unfortunately the point of p-files is exactly that they are obfuscated, *i.e.* you cannot read the source code. This is a recurent questio on SO, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080311/is-there-a-way-to-see-the-source-of-a-pcode-file-p-in-matlab) for instance.

I'm afraid you cannot read what's inside `barrier`. Maybe if you ask the Mathworks kindly they can give you some information on the content.

Best

Comment: Thanks. But where can I find barrier? Thanks.

Comment: Not a problem at all. Thank you for your reply. Do you know where I could get some descriptions for barrier at least? I mainly want to see how the three algorithms are implemented. Is there any way I can do that? Thank you so much.

Comment: I am also having the same problem with `sqpLineSearch` for algorithm "sqp"..... : (